# How to set the min-height property to dynamic width

Tags: css

I am trying to make a circle (not an oval) around any content I add inside a div to create a badge effect. I want the size to be dynamic based on the content and I only want to use CSS. Is this possible? What I have is below.

```css
.a-circle-badge {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-circle-badge"><span>2200</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *pseudo element* to make `height` equal to `width` for an element by using `padding-top` in percentages (note that padding is calculated with respect to width for an element).

Also I'm using and `inline-flex` container so that the width of the element is as much as its content - see demo below:

```css
.a-circle-badge {
  display: inline-flex; /* <-- inline flex container */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.a-circle-badge span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.a-circle-badge span::before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 100%; /* <-- will create height = width */
}
```

```html
<div class="a-circle-badge"><span>2200</span></div>
<div class="a-circle-badge"><span>Some text here</span></div>
```

Comment: I saw a similar answer to this on another post however I could not get it to work. It looks like the secret sauce I was missing was the .a-circle-badge span properties. Thank you very much for your elegant solution.